# Read data from txt file on c++

Tags: c++, rosrun, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I have a package with a c++ source file (source.cpp) that reads data from a txt (filename.txt). I compile the package through "catkin_make package" and everything goes fine.
What should I do to make the executable to find the txt file when I run "rosrun package executable"?

Edit:
In the CMakeLists.txt I do "add_executable (executable source.cpp)". The filename.txt is in the same directory as source.cpp. How do I add the file name?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207149/read-data-from-txt-file-on-c++/) by [charles](https://answers.ros.org/users/22167/charles/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-04-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alternatively to @aak2166 answer you can use the ros::package API:

`ros::package::getPath('PKG_NAME')` should give you the package path, where you can append your relative resource path to get a full path.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your C++ source code you can make a call to the parameter server, where the path to that file is stored.

In your code, with Node Handle `nh` write:

```
std::string fpath;
nh.getParam("~private_param_name", fpath);
```

And now in your launch file add the line (I believe this is how it works, I've never done it this way, you might need to experiment a bit with this):

```
<node ...>
    <param name="private_param_name" command="'$(find your_package)/src/your_text_file.txt'"
</node>
```

Or if you want to run from the command line

`rosrun your_package_name your_executable _private_param_name:="path_to_your_package/src/your_text_file.txt"`

---

Originally posted by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) with karma: 593 on 2015-04-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1